# android volley will resize(subsample) large images automatically

Tags: android, android-volley

in my app i have to download high resolution images from my server. i am planning to use volley. the image loading is work well for small images.for some high resolution images it throws out of memory exception.
i have tested with some sample images it will throw out of memory exception for some images. i also seen about sub sampling large images to display efficiently in this link [loading large images efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).i don't know it will automatically reduce the image resolution for high resolution images.

code for loading image using volley into an imageview.

```
imgloader_disk.get(url, new ImageListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Volley should be doing this automatically. please post the relevant code.

Comment: @GilMoshayof edited above with the image loading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you're using an `ImageLoader` object to launch the request to get the image you need.

`ImageLoader.get()` has an overloaded method which accepts maxWidth / maxHeight parameters which you should *always* use (unless you know for a fact that the image you're fetching is reasonably sized):

```
 public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageListener imageListener, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, boolean withCache)
```

You can use the size of the `ImageView` the image will be displayed in, or - if you don't know the size - you should use the width/height of the screen.

Once you pass these variables, Volley will take care of the rest by downscaling the image to be no larger than the desired size.

Remember, unlike iOS, Android is very restrictive with the memory you allocate in your app and this is especially prevalent with Bitmaps. You must make every effort to allocate only what you need, and release resources once you no longer need them.

Answer (score 1):

Your server must not have images large in size, No matter what library you are using you are anyhow going to have `Out of memory exception`because the default heap size for any android application is limited i.e. 16MB. As soon as you will consume that heap size either you increase it or not you are definitely going to have a Out of memory exception. So it is advised not to use high resolution images on server.

Comment: in my app i have a functionality that will give information untill 3x zooming.i am planning to use the https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view this lib for handling dynamic subsampling. but i have to give the image to the lib  as bitmap/internal file. while i try to decode the jpeg to bitmap the app throes oom

Comment: @user1992200 It is an expected behavior, Either compromise with the quality of image by scaling it down or you can use images with smaller in size. it is the only solution. Somehow Hi-End mobile phones do not get OOM but the rest of mobile phones it will be there definitely. Murphy's law is applicable here.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey What is the purpose of trying a image with 20,000*20,000 with the largest possible resolution for android devices known to be is 2560 x  1600? The hardware could only display pixels according to its limitation. Smartness exist in decoding image to the exact size of device and memory limit by loading a smaller subsampled version in memory.

Comment: The view allows you to zoom in to see the high resolution detail. It starts by showing a subsampled image and loads high res tiles as you zoom in.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey Have you read the question ? Does it say anything about zooming in? Don't downvote answers if you do not understand the question.

Comment: The OP says in the comment above he is using zoom, and says in the question he needs to download large images. There are valid reasons for downloading large images from the server (e.g. you're building a viewer for images you don't control), methods to download files over 16Mb (streaming to filesystem) and solutions for displaying these images whether you need zoom or not. Anyway, if you edit your answer I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey Be my guest. It was never about downvoting. You should always direct people in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

for  in your `AndroidManifest.xml`